# Posts doesn't have green color for accepted

Tags: support, bug, android-app, stack-overflow-app

I was browsing the new Stack Overflow APP Android (beta), and found out that in profile  the posts which are accepted doesn't have the background green color.

See below screenshot

[image: SS]

Comment: Wonder I get a downvote for reporting a bug LOL

Comment: How are you getting to that screen?  Every question I see with an accepted answer has the score filled in as green.

Comment: @makoto, just click .`..more` then you will see your profile click on ir and it will show this screen

Comment: 3 years gone by and this bug is still open and without any comment whatsoever.

Comment: At this point the actual apps aren't supported. You should use the responsive sites instead.